# GrinderStone - Not supporting latest of Grinder and Jython

Tags: load-testing, grinder

I downloaded

```
Grinder latest 3.11
Jython latest 2.5.3
Eclipse 4.2
GrinderStone - 2.5.5
```

-- And I was following the steps in [GrinderStone Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/grinderstone/w/list). But I am getting some error while creating Run Configuration for Grinder

Issue-1: Giving error when I click on new while creating new 'Grinder Run' from Run Configurations popup window.
The error is:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.python.pydev.plugin.PydevPlugin.log(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

Issue-2: After filling the project, Main module, grinder.properties, it not showing any thing in "PYTHONPATH that will be used in the run" test, actually it should show all the jar files and source paths and ect.

And more, Apply, Run buttons are disabled state.

**Please help me with any working set of versions of above needed softwares. I thing there is some incompatibilities in my list of versions of the softwares I installed.**

I read some blogs, but those are referring very old versions of softwares. And they are saying later versions also will work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the latest version of the plugin does not work with grinder> 3.6. The interfaces in the Grinder on the plug touches were greatly changed. I have the Stone Grinder plugin and the Python scripts adjusted as far as one can debug a Grinderrun least now, on occasion I will make this release times online. 
regards 
Peter Laue

Comment: I have a similar problem with grinder 3.11, Jython 2.7.0 and Grinderstone 2.5.5. I would like to see your improvements online.